# Using a 15V input with either a 24V or 12V input transformer?

Tags: transformer

I have a circuit built and I have an output of 15V AC. I want to step it up to at least 100-120V.

Now all I can find is 12V or 24V to 117V transformers. Let's say both transformers are rated at 48VA.

Can I connect a 15V supply to the 12V side of the transformer (assuming I don't go over its rated power)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 15 VAC is somewhere around 60 Hz, the 12 volt transformer should produce about 146 volts.

I've used 12/120V 60Hz transformers at ~300 Hz with no apparent problems - but didn't measure losses or other inefficiencies.

Comment: hmm ok as i thought. So exceeding the voltage rating is fine as long as I keep in mind the load / current drawn

Comment: I'd expect 15 V instead of 12 to be OK, but probably wouldn't go above 20 V into a 12V winding.  In the application I mentioned, I think we actually got about 200V out of the 120V primary, without producing any smoke.